# How to fix $injector:modulerr?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to fix angular.js:99 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=home&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angul.......1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A57)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fangular-1.7.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A370)
```

?

```
<script src="/angular-1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-1.7.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="/angular-1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<link href="/angular-1.7.8/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap-material-design.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS code

```
angular.module('home', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);
```

it will work without ngSanitize, but I need it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include cdn for ngSanitize and cdn is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```